# Nokogiri, fetch all classes from page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

How can I get an array of all classes from a html page?

I am trying like this

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)
page.classes
=> []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#classes` returns only classes of the node itself. It doesn't deal with the child nodes. You need to scan all the child nodes recursively.

```rb
require 'nokogiri'

def flatten_dom(node)
  node.elements.flat_map { |child| flatten(child) } << node
end

page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse('<html><body class="a b"><b class="c">x</b></body></html>')

flatten(page).flat_map(&:classes)
# => ["c", "a", "b"]
```

You may also want to add `.uniq` in order to get rid of the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it to get all classes of a page with Nokogiri:

```rb
def classes(element)
  (
    element.attr('class').to_s.split +
    element.children.map { |c| classes(c) }
  ).flatten.compact
end

page = Nokogiri::HTML(File.read('a.html'))

classes(page)

# => ["max-w-md", "my-4", "p-4", "mx-auto", "bg-gray-200", "bg-gray-300", "rounded", "mb-4", "block", "no-underline", "overflow-hidden", "flex", "w-20", "h-32", "bg-cover", "bg-no-repeat", "bg-center", "overflow-hidden", "font-bold", "px-4", "pt-2", "underline", "truncate", "px-4", "truncate", "text-sm", "px-4", "truncate", "text-sm", "px-4", "truncate", "text-sm", "text-gray-600", "px-4", "truncate", "text-sm", "rounded-full", "w-5", "mr-1", "inline-block", ...]
```